# Controller return `false` while DashboardController return `true`

Tags: laravel

I am running laravel 6.11

and by default we have this

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        dd(Auth::check());    
    }
}
```

and I have defined my controller like this,

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display dashboard
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {       
        dd(Auth::check());
    }
}
```

Now the user successfully login,

and visiting same page, dashboard at different time

Controller return `false` while DashboardController return `true`

Why is that?

Comment: because of the define auth in web.php thats why

Comment: please pput your web.php

Comment: I added my web.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As of Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors), you can't access the session (including Auth) in the controller constructor. You can, however, define a middleware closure in the constructor that will have access to the session.

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            dd(Auth::check());    
        });
    }
}
```